# Does boost or STL have a predicate for comparing two char values?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, stl

I need to call `boost::trim_left_if` on a single `char` value:

```
// pseudo code; not tested.
std::string to_trim{"hello"};
char left_char = 'h';
boost::algorithm::trim_left_if(to_trim, /*left_char?*/);
```

In the last line above, I need a way to pass in the `char` value. I looked around but I didn't see a generic predicate in Boost or STL to simply compare two arbitrary values. I could use lambdas for this but would prefer the predicate, if one exists.

One thing I want to avoid here is using `boost::is_any_of()` or any other predicates that would require `left_char` to be converted to a string.

Comment: Can't you use a lambda? `[&](char c) { return c == left_char; }`.

Comment: `is_from_range(left_char, left_char)`?

Comment: @T.C. the range isn't half-open?

Comment: @Yakk Not according to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/is_from_range.html).

Comment: @T.C. I sort of get why, but meh.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos I mentioned lambda in my question and explained my reasoning for avoiding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since C++11, the idiomatic way to compare for equality to a fixed value is to use a bind-expression with `std::equal_to`:

```
boost::algorithm::trim_left_if(to_trim,
    std::bind(std::equal_to<>{}, left_char, std::placeholders::_1));
```

This uses the transparent predicate `std::equal_to<void>` (since C++14); in C++11 use `std::equal_to<char>`.

Prior to C++11 (and, likely, until C++17) you can use `std::bind1st` in place of `std::bind` and `std::placeholders::_1`.

Remaining within Boost, you could also use `boost::algorithm::is_any_of` with a unitary range; I find `boost::assign::list_of` works well:

```
boost::algorithm::trim_left_if(to_trim,
    boost::algorithm::is_any_of(boost::assign::list_of(left_char)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write one?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp>

struct Pred
{
    Pred(char ch) : ch_(ch) {}
    bool operator () ( char c ) const { return ch_ == c; }
    char ch_;
};

int main ()
{
    std::string to_trim{"hello"};
    char left_char = 'h';
    boost::algorithm::trim_left_if(to_trim, Pred(left_char));
    std::cout << to_trim << std::endl;
}
```

Seriously - the stuff in boost is not "sent down from on high", it's written by people like you and me.